# How to retrieve regularisation term from xgboost

Tags: python, boosting, bias-variance-tradeoff

To evaluate the bias-variance tradeoff, I prefer to plot [the prediction error vs. the complexity of the trained estimator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpqa6.jpg).

In case of xgboost [the documentation states that the complexity is taken as the regularisation term of the objective function](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html). So in principle it should be easy to generate such a plot.

However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the calculated regularisation term for the trained model. I am using the Python scikit-learn API.

Is this value available in the library, or should it be recomputed after training?

Comment: I think something is misinterpreted here. The regularisation terms is penalising the complexity of the model. The complexity of the model itself (assuming fixed choice of hyperparameters) is reflected by the increased number of boosting iterations. For the plot you are trying to recreated you just plot the loss against the number of iterations performed.

Comment: You state 'complexity of the model itself ... assuming fixed choice of parameters'. My question pertains exactly to this point: a grid search yields different models with different complexities. So this is what I want to assess in the first place. Then, as a second iteration, I would plot the loss vs number of iterations like you say. Or am I completely off track here?

Comment: I am sorry I am not 100% clear what you ask but I think you are asking for example, what if in one case we had `max_depth=5` and the another `max_depth=10`, what we monitor complexity only by the number of iterations?